# Onde fica a pasta de log do SAP Hybris?

Tags: java, log, erp

Após executar o comando: `ant clean all` no console, gostaria de ler o log completo dos erros gerados pela compilação do hybris.

Alguém sabe me dizer em que pasta ele guarda esse arquivo de log?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

fica nesse caminho: 
{yourDirectory}/hybris/log

Comment: muito obrigado chara!